# How to transform traditional query into Laravel E.L.O.Q.U.E.N.T QUERY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Can someone help me to convert this query into Laravel ELOQUENT? The query is below on the screenshot link and also on comment section

```
DB::select('SELECT t1.*
    FROM messages AS t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS sender_id,
            GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS receiver_id,
            MAX(id) AS max_id
        FROM messages
        GROUP BY
            LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id),
            GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
    ) AS t2
        ON LEAST(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = t2.sender_id AND
           GREATEST(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = t2.receiver_id AND
           t1.id = t2.max_id
        WHERE t1.sender_id = ? OR t1.receiver_id = ?
    ', [$id, $id]);
```

Comment: atleast show us what yo've tried and where you're failing

Comment: I was making a messenger type thing and I want to get the chat list with the latest message send by either sender or receiver using eloquent.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: No bro  I want to convert my working query into Eloquent with query builder

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have two variables to store sender and receiver id for filtering.

```
$sender_id = 10;
$receiver_id = 12;
$sub =  DB::table('messages')
            ->selectRaw(
                "LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS sender_id,
                GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS receiver_id,
                MAX(id) AS max_id"
            )
            ->groupByRaw('LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)');

$main   =   DB::table('messages as t1')
                ->joinSub($sub, 't2', function ($join) {
                    $join->on(function($query){
                        return $query->whereRaw('LEAST(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = t2.sender_id')
                                    ->whereRaw('GREATEST(t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id) = t2.receiver_id')
                                    ->whereRaw('t1.id = t2.max_id');
                    });
                })
                ->selectRaw('t1.*')
                ->where('t1.sender_id', '=', $sender_id)
                ->where('t1.receiver_id', '=', $receiver_id)
                ->get();
```

You can replace `get` with `toSql` method to see what query will be generated.

Also I used multiple `whereRaw` in `on` clause to increase the readability, you can merge them in single `whereRaw` too.

See also [Joining distinct table in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073949/joining-distinct-tables-in-laravel/64074359#64074359) for more info.